# Do wet dreams invalidate the fast in Ramadan?

Tags: sawm, ramadan, taharah, nocturnal-emission

I feel a little embarrassed to ask this. I woke up and realized that I had a wet dream and I needed to perform ghusl (released semen). I did not have enough time to do ghusl so I prayed fajr (without performing ghusl) because there was only 10 mins before sunrise. This never happened to me before and I was really embarrassed. Is my fast valid despite this?

Answer (score 4):

```
              In The Name of Allah, The Most Beneficent, The Most Merciful.
```

Wet dreams during the day in Ramadan does not invalidate the fast because it is not intentional. The Qur'an says (interpretation of the meaning):

> “Allaah burdens not a person beyond his scope” [Qur'an 2:286]

The Messenger of Allah said:

> "Three things do not break the fast of the fasting person: Cupping,
>   vomiting, and the wet dream." [Jami` at-Tirmidhi 719, grade   : da'if.]

Answer (score 0):

Yes because you didn't do it intentionally,

UNLESS you masturbate if that's what you mean "I needed to ghusl (release semen), then you have to make up your fast.

Don't be embarrassed its human nature

(do a proper ghusl and don't be worried if you don't pray on time all it matters if you pray, if you forget and remember do it on the spot. but it's always better to pray on time)