# Should I continue the fast after experiencing a wet dream?

Tags: sawm, ramadan, ghusl, nocturnal-emission

I was taking a nap in the afternoon of Ramadan and experienced a wet dream.
Am I allowed to continue the fast? Is my fast valid? Am I required to take a bath?

Comment: Your fast is valid and you should continue fasting and make ghusl as soon as possible.

Comment: See also http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/33064/do-wet-dreams-invalidate-the-fast-in-ramadan

Comment: @Medi1Saif you are giving answer in comment section

Comment: @nim well the link i gave is a clear duplicate only because somebody has downvoted the answer there i couldn't mark it as duplicate. So why should i answer?

Answer (score 0):

> I was taking a nap in the afternoon of Ramadan and experienced a wet
>   dream. Am I allowed to continue the fast?

Yes, you should continue the fast.

> Is my fast valid?

Yes, your fast is valid because wet dreams don't invalidate fasts.

> Am I required to take a bath?

You should take a bath as soon as possible.